# Changing the backgroundcolor of drop-down List with C# and Excel.Interop

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I would like to use different background colors for the elements in the drop-down list. I generated the drop-down as follow:

```
var list = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
list.Add("okay");
list.Add("delete");
list.Add("else (Comment)");
var myDDL = string.Join(",", list.ToArray());
var celldd = (Excel.Range)mysheet.Cells[row_counter, 10];
celldd.Validation.Delete();

try
{
    int type = celldd.Validation.Type;
    Console.WriteLine("The validation have already been added");
 }
 catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
 {
    celldd.Validation.Add(
          Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList,
          Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation,
          Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween,
          myDDL, misValue);
 }
 celldd.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
 celldd.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
 celldd.Locked = false;
 celldd.Value2 = "Choose";
 celldd.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Plum);
```

Is this possible? Until now, just the default value has a background color.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to control the background color of drop-down list. It is however possible to format cell based on (selected) value using [conditional formatting](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/cond_format1_2010.php).

Comment: Is it possible to work with `Excel.DropDowns myDDL;` and then change the attribute of the items with `myDDL.Item(1).Attributes.Add(...)`?

Comment: [`Worksheet.DropDowns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.dropdowns?view=excel-pia) represents a collection of drop-down controls in the worksheet. It is similar to [`Buttons`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.buttons?view=excel-pia), [`CheckBoxes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.checkboxes?view=excel-pia) and other collections of form controls. These can be inserted in `Developer` tab of MS Excel and have nothing to do with validation lists.

Comment: Excel interop can't do something that's not already possible with Excel itself. *Can* you change the background in Excel? If so, you can record a VBA macro while you do that and then inspect the calls. VBA calls the same API as Excel Interop which means you can replicate those calls in your C# code

Comment: I tried to solve it like @Peter supposed it. The conditional formatting works without troubles if there is no drop-down list (ie the background will changed to red if there is a cellvalue "delete"). But i get an error message if i have DDL in the column `J` :
`Excel.FormatCondition condition = sheet_adv_output.get_Range("J2:J10",
            Type.Missing).FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, "=\"delete\"", misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
condition.Interior.ColorIndex = 3;`